# How can I show a picture before a link in google sites

Tags: google-sites

I have a website that i've set up through google sites. I have a link to an external webpage. What I'd really like to have happen is, if someone clicks the link, it shows a jpg picture for about 5 seconds and then forwards them off to the linked website. Is there a way to do that?

Thanks,
Rich

Answer (score 0):

Adding to following tag:

```
<META http-equiv="refresh" content="5;URL=http://example.com">
```

to the `<head>` section of a webpage will redirect the user to example.com, or whatever the `URL` value is. You can display an image in the `<body>` section of this page. This seems like the simplest way to accomplish what you want.

Comment: from what i can tell, google sites doesn't allow editing to the <head> section of a document, so I can't figure out how to make this work